# How to autocomplete formulas in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: shortcut-keys, auto-completion, libreoffice

I recently moved from MS Excel 2007 to LibreOffice Calc (now using Ubuntu 11.10) and there are some things that I still cannot do in LibreOffice Calc. One of these things is formula autocompletion.

In Excel, if I type `=av`, Excel shows me a list of formulas, and then I can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete the formula. In LibreOffice Calc, if I write `=av`, it shows me the alternative `=AVERAGE` but if I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it does not autocomplete. The cursor simply moves to the next cell.

Is it possible to configure LibreOffice Calc to autocomplete formulas by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> or some other shortcut?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Works like  a charm.

Comment: That couldn't have been so obvious... Even though, I've never tried that out =$ ... Thank you!